# Akka Tcp create peer to peer architecture instead of client server

Tags: scala, sockets, tcp, akka

In the current Akka documentation there is a [nice example of creating a client server architecture](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/io-tcp.html#Connecting). I'm creating a Akka actor that can send and receive messages on the bitcoin protocol. So far I've been able to send messages & receive replies to the message I sent, but I haven't been able to receive unsolicited messages as required on the peer to peer protocol.

I've tried to use `Tcp.Bind` and `Tcp.Connect` to be able to listen to unsolicited messages on port `18333` whistle also being able to send messages to a peer on the network. However, I run into this issue where it will say that the port is already bound (by the `Tcp.Connect` event) or it won't be able to send messages from that port (due to the `Tcp.Bind` event).

How can I send messages and receive unsolicited messages on the same port? Am I missing something here?

```
sealed trait Client extends Actor with BitcoinSLogger {

  /**
    * The address of the peer we are attempting to connect to
    * on the p2p network
    * @return
    */
  def remote: InetSocketAddress

  /**
    * The actor that is listening to all communications between the
    * client and its peer on the network
    * @return
    */
  def listener : ActorRef


  def actorSystem : ActorSystem
  /**
    * The manager is an actor that handles the underlying low level I/O resources (selectors, channels)
    * and instantiates workers for specific tasks, such as listening to incoming connections.
    */
  def manager : ActorRef = IO(Tcp)(actorSystem)


  /**
    * This actor signifies the node we are connected to on the p2p network
    * This is set when we received a [[Tcp.Connected]] message
    */
  private var peer : Option[ActorRef] = None

  def receive = {
    case message : Tcp.Message => message match {
      case event : Tcp.Event =>
        logger.debug("Event: " + event)
        handleEvent(event)
      case command : Tcp.Command =>
        logger.debug("Command: " + command)
        handleCommand(command)
    }
    case unknownMessage => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown message for client: " + unknownMessage)
  }

  /**
    * This function is responsible for handling a [[Tcp.Event]] algebraic data type
    * @param event
    */
  private def handleEvent(event : Tcp.Event) = event match {
    case Tcp.Bound(localAddress) =>
      logger.debug("Actor is now bound to the local address: " + localAddress)
    case Tcp.CommandFailed(w: Tcp.Write) =>
      logger.debug("Client write command failed: " + Tcp.CommandFailed(w))
      logger.debug("O/S buffer was full")
      // O/S buffer was full
      //listener ! "write failed"
    case Tcp.CommandFailed(command) =>
      logger.debug("Client Command failed:" + command)
    case Tcp.Received(data) =>
      logger.debug("Received data from our peer on the network: " + BitcoinSUtil.encodeHex(data.toArray))
      //listener ! data
    case Tcp.Connected(remote, local) =>
      logger.debug("Tcp connection to: " + remote)
      logger.debug("Local: " + local)
      peer = Some(sender)
      peer.get ! Tcp.Register(listener)
      listener ! Tcp.Connected(remote,local)
    case Tcp.ConfirmedClosed =>
      logger.debug("Client received confirmed closed msg: " + Tcp.ConfirmedClosed)
      peer = None
      context stop self
  }
  /**
    * This function is responsible for handling a [[Tcp.Command]] algebraic data type
    * @param command
    */
  private def handleCommand(command : Tcp.Command) = command match {
    case Tcp.ConfirmedClose =>
      logger.debug("Client received connection closed msg: " + Tcp.ConfirmedClose)
      listener ! Tcp.ConfirmedClose
      peer.get ! Tcp.ConfirmedClose
  }

}


case class ClientImpl(remote: InetSocketAddress, network : NetworkParameters,
                      listener: ActorRef, actorSystem : ActorSystem) extends Client {

  manager ! Tcp.Bind(listener, new InetSocketAddress(network.port))
  //this eagerly connects the client with our peer on the network as soon
  //as the case class is instantiated
  manager ! Tcp.Connect(remote)

}

object Client {


  def props(remote : InetSocketAddress, network : NetworkParameters, listener : ActorRef, actorSystem : ActorSystem) : Props = {
    Props(classOf[ClientImpl], remote, network, listener, actorSystem)
  }

  def apply(remote : InetSocketAddress, network : NetworkParameters, listener : ActorRef, actorSystem : ActorSystem) : ActorRef = {
   actorSystem.actorOf(props(remote, network, listener, actorSystem))
  }

  def apply(network : NetworkParameters, listener : ActorRef, actorSystem : ActorSystem) : ActorRef = {
    //val randomSeed = ((Math.random() * 10) % network.dnsSeeds.size).toInt
    val remote = new InetSocketAddress(network.dnsSeeds(0), network.port)
    Client(remote, network, listener, actorSystem)
  }
```

EDIT: Adding test case that is using my actor

```
  "Client" must "connect to a node on the bitcoin network, " +
    "send a version message to a peer on the network and receive a version message back, then close that connection" in {
    val probe = TestProbe()
    val client = Client(TestNet3, probe.ref, system)

    val conn : Tcp.Connected = probe.expectMsgType[Tcp.Connected]

    val versionMessage = VersionMessage(TestNet3, conn.localAddress.getAddress,conn.remoteAddress.getAddress)
    val networkMessage = NetworkMessage(TestNet3, versionMessage)
    client ! networkMessage
    val receivedMsg = probe.expectMsgType[Tcp.Received](5.seconds)

    //~~~~~~~~THIS IS WHERE THE TEST IS FAILING~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    //the bitcoin protocol states that after exchanging version messages a verack message is sent if the version message is accepted
    //this is appearing on wireshark, but not being found by my actor
    val verackMessage = probe.expectMsgType[Tcp.Received](2.seconds)

  }
```

EDIT2:

Wireshark output showing that I am receiving these messages, and akka is not registering them

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core abstraction of Akka is Actors, so peers in Tcp are just Actors that you can receive messages from AND send messages to.

In this case you can get the `ActorRef` of your peer by calling `sender()` once you've received a `Tcp.Connected` message. In your code you are already saving that ref in `peer`. It should be as simple as `peer.get ! Write(data)` to send arbitrary data back to that peer.

Since the connection could break at any point, the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/io-tcp.html) appear to be using actor supervision to handle this:

```
class SimpleClient(connection: ActorRef, remote: InetSocketAddress)
    extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  import Tcp._

  // sign death pact: this actor terminates when connection breaks
  context watch connection
  ...
}
```

---

Update

(This took me way too long to realize.) The issue you are having is that you are not explicitly handling message framing: i.e the mechanics of buffer accumulation and message reconstruction. Akka TCP only hands you raw buffers. These buffers do NOT necessarily break on message boundaries, or even know anything about the messages of the higher-level protocols, like BitCoin, that ride TCP.

If you run the test case, the listener receives a Tcp.Receive message containing 1244 bytes of data. From this the unit test extracts a `NetworkHeader` and a `VersionMessage`, but it's entirely possible there are more messages in this buffer to be extracted and processed, depending on the specifics of the bitcoin protocol, but that it not handled. Instead the buffer is discarded and the test case waits for a second buffer (that may or may not ever arrive) and constructs from this buffer another message, with the hidden expectation it just happens to be perfectly byte-aligned.

Architecturally I would recommend creating a new actor specifically to handle message framing. This actor would receive the raw bits and reconstruct completed messages to send on down to the listener.

Comment: This did not work. In my test case I `probe.expectMsgType[Tcp.Received](2.seconds)` and according to wireshark I am receiving a message from that same ip address, however akka is not registering ti

Comment: Your handler for Tcp.Connected registers a different actor to listen for incoming data, bound to the val listener in your example. Does that actor exist? Why aren't you using the self actor to have the client itself respond to those messages?

Comment: The `listener` actor in this example is actually a `TestProbe` in my test case. I'll post the test case so you can see

Comment: I think you are confused between what it means to have an Object which is a sub-type of the Actor class, and what it means to have an Akka Actor. In your test case neither TestProbe nor Client are instantiated using `Props` and `system.actorOf`, which means they are Objects and NOT Actors! You may want to take a second and re-read http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html to make sure you really understand what is going here. A good rule of thumb is that an Actor will be bound to a variable of type `ActorRef`.

Comment: Also isn't `connection` in your example the same thing as `sender` when receiving a `Tcp.Connected` message?

Comment: `probe.ref` returns an `ActorRef`, which was is passed into `Client` which is parameterized to take an `ActorRef`.

Comment: Sure but where is the Actor bound to `probe.ref` instantiated in your test case? Could you post the code for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115883/discussion-between-chris-stewart-and-mark-kegel).

Answer (score 0):

TCP sockets have a propery `SO_REUSEADDR`, which I believe you can enable here using either

```
.reuseAddress(true)
```

on your socket object

or

[here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/http/configuration.html) I see a `socket-options` array that includes this property:

```
socket-options {
  so-receive-buffer-size = undefined
  so-send-buffer-size = undefined
  so-reuse-address = undefined
  so-traffic-class = undefined
  tcp-keep-alive = undefined
  tcp-oob-inline = undefined
  tcp-no-delay = undefined
}
```

I think this is what you were looking for, but I may have misunderstood the question.